# Puppet 3rd party module with custom types in masterless mode

Tags: rabbitmq, puppet

I would like to use [puppet-rabbitmq](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-rabbitmq) module. With other 3rd party modules (like postgresql), we simply copied the sources of the module under our `modules/` directory and everything was working.

With puppet-rabbitmq, I get this error when trying to declare a queue:

> Error: Could not find a suitable provider for rabbitmq_queue

This is how I declare the queue:

```
  rabbitmq_queue { 'testqueue@/':
    ensure      => present,
    user        => $username,
    password    => $password,
    durable     => true,
  }
```

My suspicion is that the difference from the other 3rd party modules is that `rabbitmq_queue` is a custom type (see [sources](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-rabbitmq/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/rabbitmq_queue/rabbitmqadmin.rb)).

Do custom types work with masterless mode? How can I get `rabbitmq_queue` working in it?

Comment: This usually implies the provider is not present in your system. Do you have what is needed for rabbitmq_queue installed on the server?

Comment: I have rabbitmq installed all right, including rabbitmqctl. But I didn't install it using puppet-rabbitmq. Do you think that's the problem?

Comment: Do you have the necessary rabbitmq packages installed to support the provider needs listed here from 5 to 15: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-rabbitmq/blob/master/lib/puppet/provider/rabbitmq_queue/rabbitmqadmin.rb#L5